# When I am running my app on emulator it showing main activity as app name intead of the original

Tags: android

```
package com.example.sunshine;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
     {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return true;
     }

     // Method to start the service
     public void startService(View view)
     {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
     }

     // Method to stop the service
     public void stopService(View view)
     {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with this code. It might be in the other place

Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, there you should see

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Check if in your manifest file this field exist and which value it already has.